# Adding column with header to pipe-delimited file using awk or sed

Tags: unix, awk, sed, data-cleaning

I am trying to add a column with a header "DATE" and the value equal to the date "DD-MM-YY". The issue I am having is that the code I run adds the "DATE" and "DD-MM-YY values to the second column of a new  row instead of appending to the existing rows in the data.

I've tried using both awk and sed, but both produce the same results. Below is my current code, my original data, the data resulting from my code, and my desired dataset.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
for y in 2021 
        do
for m in  02
        do
for d in 01 
        do 
 awk -v d=$y-$m-$d -F"|" 'BEGIN {OFS = "|"} FNR==1{$(NF+1)="DATE"} FNR>1{$(NF+1)=d;} 1' Corporate_bond_mstr-$y-$m-$d.txt > check.txt  
done
done
done
```

and

```
sed  -e '1s/$/|DATE/' -e "2,\$s/$/|$y-$m-$d/" -e 's/\>|/ |/g' Corporate_bond_mstr-$y-$m-$d.txt > changed_$y-$m-$d.csv | column -s '|' -t
```

**ORIGINAL DATA**

```
FINRA_SCRTY_ID|CUSIP_ID|SYM_CD|CMPNY_NM|SUB_PRDCT_TYPE_CD   
3698282|000336AC1|ANTM3698282|AAG HLDG INC|CORP|CORP   
3698282|000336AC1|ANTM3698282|AAG HLDG INC|CORP|BOND   
3698282|000336AC1|ANTM3698282|AAG HLDG INC|CORP|GOVT
```

**DATA AFTER RUNNING CODE**

```
FINRA_SCRTY_ID|CUSIP_ID|SYM_CD|CMPNY_NM|SUB_PRDCT_TYPE_CD   
       |DATE   
3698282|000336AC1|ANTM3698282|AAG HLDG INC|CORP|CORP   
       |DD-MM-YY   
3698282|000336AC1|ANTM3698282|AAG HLDG INC|CORP|BOND   
       |DD-MM-YY   
3698282|000336AC1|ANTM3698282|AAG HLDG INC|CORP|GOVT   
       |DD-MM-YY
```

**DESIRED DATA**

```
FINRA_SCRTY_ID|CUSIP_ID|SYM_CD|CMPNY_NM|SUB_PRDCT_TYPE_CD|DATE   
3698282|000336AC1|ANTM3698282|AAG HLDG INC|CORP|CORP|DD-MM-YY   
3698282|000336AC1|ANTM3698282|AAG HLDG INC|CORP|BOND|DD-MM-YY   
3698282|000336AC1|ANTM3698282|AAG HLDG INC|CORP|GOVT|DD-MM-YY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed this will produce the desired data:

```
y=YY m=MM d=DD
sed -e '1s/[ ]*$/|DATE/' \
    -e '2,$s/[ ]*$/|'"$d-$m-$y"'/' data
```

Perhaps the `column` command is tricking you; try running without.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but even without the column command I get the same results. I'm a fairly novice user and I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out and it keeps being trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get rid of carriage returns in the text file for the code to run correctly.

sed -e 's/[\r\n]//g'  Corporate_bond_mstr-$y-$m-$d.txt >  chg1.txt
sed  -e '0,/|CNVRB_FL/s//|CNVRB_FL| /'   chg1.txt  > chg.txt
sed  -e '1s/$/DATE/' -e "2,$s/$/|$y-$m-$d/" -e 's/>|/ |/g' chg.txt > Corporate_bond_mstr-$y-$m-$d.txt